# Prim's MST algorithm implementation with Java

Tags: java, prims-algorithm

I'm trying to write a program that'll find the MST of a given undirected weighted graph with Kruskal's and Prim's algorithms. I've successfully implemented Kruskal's algorithm in the program, but I'm having trouble with Prim's. To be more precise, I can't figure out how to actually build the Prim function so that it'll iterate through all the vertices in the graph. I'm getting some IndexOutOfBoundsException errors during program execution. I'm not sure how much information is needed for others to get the idea of what I have done so far, but hopefully there won't be too much useless information.

This is what I have so far:

I have a `Graph`, `Edge` and a `Vertex` class.

- Vertex class mostly just an information storage that contains the name (number) of the vertex.
- Edge class can create a new Edge that has gets parameters `(Vertex start, Vertex end, int edgeWeight)`. The class has methods to return the usual info like start vertex, end vertex and the weight.
- Graph class reads data from a text file and adds new Edges to an ArrayList. The text file also tells us how many vertecis the graph has, and that gets stored too.

In the `Graph` class, I have a Prim() -method that's supposed to calculate the MST:

```
    public ArrayList<Edge> Prim(Graph G) {

    ArrayList<Edge> edges = G.graph; // Copies the ArrayList with all edges in it.
    ArrayList<Edge> MST = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    Random rnd = new Random();

    Vertex startingVertex = edges.get(rnd.nextInt(G.returnVertexCount())).returnStartingVertex(); // This is just to randomize the starting vertex.

    // This is supposed to be the main loop to find the MST, but this is probably horribly wrong..
    while (MST.size() < returnVertexCount()) {

        Edge e = findClosestNeighbour(startingVertex);
        MST.add(e);
        visited.add(e.returnStartingVertex());
        visited.add(e.returnEndingVertex());
        edges.remove(e);

    }

    return MST;
}
```

The method findClosesNeighbour() looks like this:

```
public Edge findClosestNeighbour(Vertex v) {

    ArrayList<Edge> neighbours = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    ArrayList<Edge> edges = graph;

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size() -1; ++i) {

        if (edges.get(i).endPoint() == s.returnVertexID() && !visited(edges.get(i).returnEndingVertex())) {

            neighbours.add(edges.get(i));
        }
    }

    return neighbours.get(0); // This is the minimum weight edge in the list.
}
```

`ArrayList<Vertex> visited` and `ArrayList<Edges> graph` get constructed when creating a new graph.

Visited() -method is simply a boolean check to see if ArrayList visited contains the Vertex we're thinking about moving to. I tested the `findClosestNeighbour()` independantly and it seemed to be working but if someone finds something wrong with it then that feedback is welcome also.

Mainly though as I mentioned my problem is with actually building the main loop in the Prim() -method, and if there's any additional info needed I'm happy to provide it.

Thank you.

Edit: To clarify what my train of thought with the Prim() method is. What I want to do is first randomize the starting point in the graph. After that, I will find the closest neighbor to that starting point. Then we'll add the edge connecting those two points to the MST, and also add the vertices to the visited list for checking later, so that we won't form any loops in the graph.

Here's the error that gets thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Graph.findClosestNeighbour(graph.java:203)
    at Graph.Prim(graph.java:179)
    at MST.main(MST.java:49)
```

Line 203: `return neighbour.get(0);` in findClosestNeighbour()

Line 179: `Edge e = findClosestNeighbour(startingVertex);` in Prim()

Comment: Which line throws the IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: So ... put it in the debugger and step through it to find out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vertex startingVertex = edges.get(rnd.nextInt(G.returnVertexCount())).returnStartingVertex();
```

This uses the vertex count to index an edge list, mixing up vertices and edges.

```
// This is supposed to be the main loop to find the MST, but this is probably horribly wrong..
while (MST.size() < returnVertexCount()) {

    Edge e = findClosestNeighbour(startingVertex);
    MST.add(e);
    visited.add(e.returnStartingVertex());
    visited.add(e.returnEndingVertex());
    edges.remove(e);
}
```

This shouldn't be passing the same startingVertex to findClosestNeighbour each time.

```
public Edge findClosestNeighbour(Vertex v) {

    ArrayList<Edge> neighbours = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    ArrayList<Edge> edges = graph;

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size() -1; ++i) {

        if (edges.get(i).endPoint() == s.returnVertexID() && !visited(edges.get(i).returnEndingVertex())) {

            neighbours.add(edges.get(i));
        }
    }

    return neighbours.get(0); // This is the minimum weight edge in the list.
}
```

What is `s` here? This doesn't look like it's taking the edge weights into account. It's skipping the last edge, and it's only checking the ending vertex, when the edges are non-directional.

Comment: `s` is a type since I translated my code from my native language to english, and is supposed to be the Vertex `v`. I'll look into the things you said and will try and look into some debugging tools like Brian suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Simple weighted graph representation 
// Uses an Adjacency Linked Lists, suitable for sparse graphs /*undirected
```

9
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
A B 1
B C 2
C E 7
E G 1
G H 8
F H 3
F D 4
D E 5
I F 9
I A 3
A D 1 
This is the graph i used saved as graph.txt
*/

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Heap
{
    private int[] h;       // heap array
    private int[] hPos;    // hPos[h[k]] == k
    private int[] dist;    // dist[v] = priority of v
    private int MAX;

    private int N;         // heap size

    // The heap constructor gets passed from the Graph:
    //    1. maximum heap size
    //    2. reference to the dist[] array
    //    3. reference to the hPos[] array
    public Heap(int maxSize, int[] _dist, int[] _hPos) 
    {
        N = 0;
        MAX = maxSize;
        h = new int[maxSize + 1];
        dist = _dist;
        hPos = _hPos;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
        return N == 0;
    }


    public void siftUp( int k) 
    {
        int v = h[k];

        h[0] = 0;
        dist[0] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        //vertex using dist moved up heap
        while(dist[v] < dist[h[k/2]]){


            h[k] = h[k/2]; //parent vertex is assigned pos of child vertex

            hPos[h[k]] = k;//hpos modified for siftup

            k = k/2;// index of child assigned last parent to continue siftup
        }

        h[k] = v;//resting pos of vertex assigned to heap

        hPos[v] = k;//index of resting pos of vertex updated in hpos

        //display hpos array
       /* System.out.println("\nThe following is the hpos array after siftup: \n");

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i ++){

            System.out.println("%d", hPos[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\n Following is heap array after siftup: \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i ++ ){

            System.out.println("%d" , h[i]);

        }*/
    }


    //removing the vertex at top of heap
    //passed the index of the smallest value in heap
    //siftdown resizes and resorts heap

    public void siftDown( int k) 
    {
        int v, j;

        v = h[k];  

        while(k <= N/2){

            j = 2 * k;

            if(j < N && dist[h[j]] > dist[h[j + 1]]) ++j; //if node is > left increment j child

            if(dist[v] <= dist[h[j]]) break;//if sizeof parent vertex is less than child stop.

            h[k] = h[j];//if parent is greater than child then child assigned parent pos

            hPos[h[k]] = k;//update new pos of last child

            k = j;//assign vertex new pos
        }
        h[k] = v;//assign rest place of vertex to heap
        hPos[v] = k;//update pos of the vertex in hpos array
    }


    public void insert( int x) 
    {
        h[++N] = x;//assign new vertex to end of heap
        siftUp( N);//pass index at end of heap to siftup
    }


    public int remove() 
    {   
        int v = h[1];
        hPos[v] = 0; // v is no longer in heap
        h[N+1] = 0;  // put null node into empty spot

        h[1] = h[N--];//last node of heap moved to top
        siftDown(1);//pass index at top to siftdown

        return v;//return vertex at top of heap
    }

}

class Graph {
    class Node {
        public int vert;
        public int wgt;
        public Node next;
    }

    // V = number of vertices
    // E = number of edges
    // adj[] is the adjacency lists array
    private int V, E;
    private Node[] adj;
    private Node z;
    private int[] mst;

    // used for traversing graph
    private int[] visited;
    private int id;


    // default constructor
    public Graph(String graphFile)  throws IOException
    {
        int u, v;
        int e, wgt;
        Node t;

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(graphFile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String splits = " +";  // multiple whitespace as delimiter
        String line = reader.readLine();        
        String[] parts = line.split(splits);
        System.out.println("Parts[] = " + parts[0] + " " + parts[1]);

        V = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        E = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

        // create sentinel node
        z = new Node(); 
        z.next = z;

        // create adjacency lists, initialised to sentinel node z       
        adj = new Node[V+1];        
        for(v = 1; v <= V; ++v)
            adj[v] = z;               

       // read the edges
        System.out.println("Reading edges from text file");
        for(e = 1; e <= E; ++e)
        {
            line = reader.readLine();
            parts = line.split(splits);
            u = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            v = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); 
            wgt = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

            System.out.println("Edge " + toChar(u) + "--(" + wgt + ")--" + toChar(v));    

            // write code to put edge into adjacency matrix 
            t = new Node(); t.vert = v; t.wgt = wgt; t.next = adj[u]; adj[u] = t;

            t = new Node(); t.vert = u; t.wgt = wgt; t.next = adj[v]; adj[v] = t;    

        }          
    }

    // convert vertex into char for pretty printing
    private char toChar(int u)
    {  
        return (char)(u + 64);
    }

    // method to display the graph representation
    public void display() {
        int v;
        Node n;

        for(v=1; v<=V; ++v){
            System.out.print("\nadj[" + toChar(v) + "] ->" );
            for(n = adj[v]; n != z; n = n.next) 
                System.out.print(" |" + toChar(n.vert) + " | " + n.wgt + "| ->");    
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }


    //use the breath first approach to add verts from the adj list to heap
    //uses 3 arrays where array = # of verts in graph
    //parent array to keep track of parent verts
    // a dist matrix to keep track of dist between it and parent
    //hpos array to track pos of vert in the heap

    public void MST_Prim(int s)
    {
        int v, u;
        int wgt, wgt_sum = 0;
        int[]  dist, parent, hPos;
        Node t;

        //declare 3 arrays
        dist = new int[V + 1];
        parent = new int[V + 1];
        hPos = new int[V +1];

        //initialise arrays
        for(v = 0; v <= V; ++v){

            dist[v] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            parent[v] = 0;
            hPos[v] = 0;
        }

        dist[s] = 0;

        //d.dequeue is pq.remove

        Heap pq =  new Heap(V, dist, hPos);
        pq.insert(s);

        while (! pq.isEmpty())  
        {
            // most of alg here
            v = pq.remove();
            wgt_sum += dist[v];//add the dist/wgt of vert removed to mean spanning tree

            //System.out.println("\nAdding to MST edge {0} -- ({1}) -- {2}", toChar(parent[v]), dist[v], toChar[v]);

            dist[v] = -dist[v];//mark it as done by making it negative

            for(t = adj[v]; t != z; t = t.next){

                u = t.vert;
                wgt = t.wgt;

                if(wgt < dist[u]){ //weight less than current value

                    dist[u] = wgt;
                    parent[u] = v;

                    if(hPos[u] == 0)// not in heap insert
                        pq.insert(u);
                    else
                        pq.siftUp(hPos[u]);//if already in heap siftup the modified heap node
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.print("\n\nWeight of MST = " + wgt_sum + "\n");

        //display hPos array
        /*System.out.println("\nhPos array after siftUp: \n");

        for(int i = 0; i < V; i ++){

            System.out.println("%d", hPos[i]);
        }*/

        mst = parent;                           
    }

    public void showMST()
    {
            System.out.print("\n\nMinimum Spanning tree parent array is:\n");
            for(int v = 1; v <= V; ++v)
                System.out.println(toChar(v) + " -> " + toChar(mst[v]));
            System.out.println("");
    }

}

public class PrimLists {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int s = 2;
        String fname = "graph.txt";               

        Graph g = new Graph(fname);

        g.display();


    }


}
```